# Display Server time using Javascript in Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, time

I have a Rails app where I'm displaying the current time in realtime using Javascript.  The following code was graciously offered to me by another StackOverflow user.

```
<div id="time" class="time_display"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}

function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    // add a zero in front of numbers<10
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    t = setTimeout(function () {
        startTime()
    }, 500);
}
startTime();
</script>
```

This works excellent, but it pulls time from the client-side/client machine.  What I'd really like to do is refactor this to display the system/server time that the Rails app sits on instead of client time.

I'm admittedly horrible at Javascript and could use some help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the difference between the browser and the server time zone offset to show the server time
ex->
 send server time zone offset to local in rails and put it in a js variable accessible in the code you have above

and add this after initalizing of the today

```
 var server_time_zone_offset = 0 // this should come from the server
    var local_time_zone = today.getTimezoneOffset();
    today = new Date(today.getTime() + (server_time_zone_offset - local_time_zone)* 60000)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following.  Can you explain more in-depth in your answer on how I would get this working in my present code?  I really just need to get the time directly from the server somehow.